# How to get variable value outside IF ELSE

Tags: c#

I have a string array variable which will take filepaths based on condition but getting error as below:

```
if (chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked == true)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
else
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}

foreach (string item in filePaths)//Error: The name filePaths dose not exist in current context 
{
    //my code
}
```

Comment: Define your `filePaths` before your `if` statement. Since you define in your `if` or `else` scope, it can be accessed _only_ inside of them.

Comment: The question kind of answers itself

Comment: But how I will define a array before IF ELSE, because I don't know how much files will be retrieved from path. means I don't know the range. Please.

Comment: It would be better to declare *SearchOption* conditionally, not the whole expression.

Comment: @MaasrangaTV You know how to use `if-else` statement, `foreach` statement and `Directory.GetFiles` method but don't know how to declare a local variable?

Comment: In related news, do not say `if (blah == true)`.  That means "if it is true that blah is true then..."  It's redundant and it makes your code look like it was written by a newcomer to the language. Just say `if (blah)`.  And similarly, don't say `if (blah == false)`, say `if(!blah)`.

Comment: Also, when you write code like this, ask yourself "what is the smallest amount of stuff that can go in the `if`?".  Your code could use the `if` to set a variable of type `SearchOption`, which could then be used by a single call to `GetFiles` after the `if`. Any time you find yourself writing very similar code in two branches of an `if`, ask yourself if there is too much code inside the `if`.

Comment: @SonerGönül: There was a day in your life when you didn't know all the basic elements of programming languages; this is that day for the OP.

Answer (score 11):

Pull the variable declaration outside the method:

```
string[] filePaths;

if (chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked)
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
else
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}

// You can use filePaths here
```

Answer (score 11):

You could follow the advice of the other answers and declare `filePaths` outside the if/else. However, you are repeating yourself as the only thing that differs between the two calls is the options. So set them up first and then make the call:

```
var searchOptions = chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked 
    ? SearchOption.AllDirectories 
    : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly; 

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, searchOptions);

foreach (string item in filePaths) 
{
    //my code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your variable outside the "if" block:

```
string[] filePaths;

if (chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked == true)
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
else
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}

foreach (string item in filePaths)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define your filePaths variable outside of your if/else statements:

```
string[] filePaths;

if (chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked == true)
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
else
{
    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}

foreach (string item in filePaths)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable with the [`?:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator, you can omit the whole if, and have terser (and more confusing) code:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text,
  chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

You can define the `SearchOption` separately to make the code more readable, along these lines:

```
string searchOption = chkIncludeSubFolders.Checked 
  ? SearchOption.AllDirectories 
  : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, txtFormat.Text, searchOption);
```

Otherwise, just declare the variable before the `if`. Note that this is only a *declaration* so you are free to have it uninitialized, as long as you will (provably) initialize it afterwards.
Since you have a simple if/else, with exactly 2 branches, and you set the value of `filePaths` in both of them, the compiler is smart enough to know that the variable will definitely have a value once the `if` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Declare filepaths before if-else